# Make catsup more clingy

Tags: ketchup

I made traditional catsup with tomatoes, vinegar and spices, boiled down.

It is very tasty, but consistency is quite stiff, with a lot of structure. The problem with this is that it does not dip well. For example, with shrimp cocktail, it tends to fall off the shrimp and not stick to it.

I think the reason why regular catsup is more soupy is because it is mechanically pureed, so it gets chopped into very small particles that ultimately makes it into more of a sauce.

My catsup, which is mashed, not pureed with blades does not have this liquid nature.

Short of puree'ing it, is there any way I can saucify my catsup?

(Note that simply adding more vinegar does not help because the tomatoes keep their structure and vinegar separates out in a puddle.

Comment: How exactly do you make it?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid making a puree?

Comment: @moscafj : Sometimes it's not a 'want', but a lack of necessary equipment

Comment: @Joe partly what I was getting at...is this a style preference or a technique issue?

Comment: @moscafj : whatever it is, it's a legitimate question.  There might be a better work-around for their specific case, but if you don't have the tools, this isn't something I'd want to have to do (if it's even possible) by hand

Comment: @joe ...ok...but the OP's goals, and tools, are relevant if he wants the best possible advice.  I never questioned the question.

Comment: @moscafj : and if the person needs to finish it in the next hour before guests arrive, and the closest kitchenwares store is more than 30 minutes away?  You can give advice on alternatives in comments, but the question as asked is still a good question to have an answer to

Comment: @Joe I am not at all clear what you are arguing with me about, but if you want to move to a conversation in chat to help me understand, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

The go-to industry standard additive to ketchup to make it "optimally clingy" is xanthan gum. It makes all water-based fluids into shear-thinning non-newtonian fluids, which means they flow just okay out of a bottle, but cling to surfaces well.

If you can't (or don't want to) use that, there's a bunch of easy natural thickeners. Potato or bean puree (blend with a small amount of your ketchup to make it easy to mix in),  gelatin or potato starch (prepare hot with water, pour/mix when lukewarm). Arrowroot.

Also, consider reducing the tomatoes some before preparing the ketchup. Less water since moment one will make it thicker.

Comment: OPs problem is their catsup is too thick. How does Xanthum Gum help with that?

Comment: @bruglesco: Dilute some xanthan gum in water, dip a finger, and you have your answer. If need be, the ketchup may need to be diluted a bit; regardless of that xanthan gum makes stuff "clingy".

Comment: So does sugar. Without adding a thickening agent.

Comment: @bruglesco: ...instead, adding a substance that strongly changes the flavor, and adds a heap of empty calories?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a component: Sugar.

And if your final product is too thick then try watering it down. (I would use tomato juice.) Also if you want your tomato mash to break down more simmer it longer. (Probably needing more liquid.)